# Geometry nodes floor flip instances animation

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

I want to make the flip rotation of cube instances in the grid. Every instance should make the rotation to 180 degrees by the Y axis. Instances react to the moving specific object (empty, for example).

The main problem is that I can't save the new rotate position of the instance, and after the specific object is gone, the instance returns to the start rotation position.

The second problem I don't understand is how to specify the area of rotation of the instances. The scale of the empty object does not work. I tried to make the operation with a mesh cube instead of empty, for example, but in my node system, it did not work either.

I have one version with strange parameters in the Map Range node (it creates a big sphere area based on the empty object), but in my opinion, it is not a good and flexible solution.

And I can't understand is my version is good. The version with big amounts in map range works for me, but I want more flexibility; for example, make more chaotic like the second variant.

Please check the screen and gifs; they are two variants of falloff.

First gif and second screen: big empty area with map range:

[image: big amounts in mapp range]
[image]

Next screens with small amounts in map range:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the project to have the instance rotate when they are *inside* a target piece of geometry - this way they don't flip back. This calculation is made inside a node group. Also think the map range is more reasonable as it just uses zero to pi as the output.

[image]

[image]

And you can modify the spread of over how much distance away from the edge of the target object the flip takes place.

You should be able to use any closed piece of geometry as the target. If you want to use an open piece of geometry a slightly more complicated set up with the raycast node should do it.

[image]

I'm hoping I understood your issue.

Comment: Wow, cool. Can you please attach the blender file for learning? I have some questions and I think it will be better to check the source. Thank you!

Comment: If it possible) Thank you!

Comment: Maybe I'm dumb but I think its possible you need a certain score to be able to attach the .blend - I was only able to attach images. 

I was thinking you could copy the node structure from the images.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

[image]

1. In order to get tiles "remember" previous position, you have to use simulation zone.

[image]

I subtracted a new rotation from the current one and apply it only if it is positive. So that tiles will rotate only one way.

2. For getting proper distance, I need only location of the Empty, no need to use proximity node for that. After getting the distance between tile and Empty, I divide it by its scale, so that scale will change the effect.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But can you explain please, does this solution work only when animation starts?

Comment: Sure, this is how simulation zone works.